# Modal window issue on "Hosting WPF application inside IE"

Tags: wpf

We have a WPF application(.Net 4.0) to be hosted on IE 8. When we open wpf dialog box( we use ShowDialog()), user can still focus on dialog box's parent window and can change data. This is  wierd behavior. What should we do to restrict this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and I couldn't find an answer. The only workaround I found is this one:

```
        if ((Application.Current != null) && (Application.Current.MainWindow != null))
        {
            window.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.IsEnabled = false;
            EventHandler handler = null;

            handler = (sender, e) =>
            {
                window.Closed -= handler;
                Application.Current.MainWindow.IsEnabled = true;
            };

            window.Closed += handler;
        }
```

I disable the main window and I re-enable it once the dialog is closed. In this way the user can't interact with the main window. I hope this helps